# Can't figure out where Binary Search algorithm went wrong

Tags: c, algorithm, runtime-error, binary-search

I tried this (binary search) algorithm on C Language, whose function is to find a number from a stack of numbers in a short period of time. It is a quite popular technique. You may also read about it on Google. For me, it's not working for 54 and 35 i.e last two numbers of array. Whenever i want to search for those two numbers, it says "Item not found". For rest of the numbers, i.e first 4 numbers of array, it works fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void)
{
    int item,beg=0,end=6,mid,a[6]={10,21,32,43,54,35};
    mid=(beg+end)/2;
    mid=round(mid);
    printf("Enter the number you want to search: ");
    scanf("%d", &item);
    printf("Item you entered is %d\n",item);
    while((a[mid]!=item) & (beg<=end))
    {
        if (item<a[mid])
            end=mid-1;
        else
            beg=mid+1;
        mid=(beg+end)/2;
        mid=round(mid);
    }

    if (item==a[mid])
        printf("Your number is at location %d in array and the number is %d",mid,a[mid]);
    else
        printf("Item not found");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please learn how to format your code to make it readable. Indentation and spaces and empty lines might not matter for the compiler, but it do matter for humans trying to read and understand the code.

Comment: Furthermore, you "tried this algorithm", but what *is* the algorithm? What is the purpose of the program? What is the input you give it? What is the expected and actual output? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And edit your question to improve it, and actually *ask* a question.

Comment: Lastly, binary search requires that the collection you're searching in is *sorted*.

Comment: Also, why are you rounding an int? `mid` is always an int here, so the result of `(beg+end)/2` will be truncated to an integer.

Comment: Shouldn't end be 5 at the start? When you search for 99 you end up accessing a[6], which is out-of-bounds.

Comment: a[mid]!=item) & (beg<=end) is a binary and: use &&

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Binary search requires the input collection (array in your case) to be **sorted**, which is not the case here.

Change:

```
a[6] = {10, 21, 32, 43, 54, 35};
```

to this:

```
a[6] = {10, 21, 32, 35, 43, 54};
```

which is the sorted version of your array.

Moreover, change:

```
end=5
```

to this:

```
end=6,
```

since the `end` should be equal to the size of your array - 1, before you enter the loop, as you can see in the [pseudocode](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Binary_search).

---

PS: This `mid=round(mid);` is not needed, since the result of the integer division will be an integer as well.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow both should work now with the array sorted.

Comment: Yeah, With the bad sorting it checks 43 and then 35 and then breaks down. It doesn't go back down to 54. It's a followup effect from 35 being out of order.

Comment: It works perfect now. Thanks loads @GoswinvonBrederlow

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow you were right, I checked the algorithm and it seems that `end` should be equal to 5, not 6! You are welcome use9181286, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @user9181286 is there any reason for un-accepting my answer?

Comment: @gsamaras ops I am really sorry. I mistakenly thanked him(@Goswin von Bredeelow) in carelessness. I wanted to say you thanks :D Thank You!

Comment: @gsamaras can you please give me +1 vote to my question?

Comment: I have already upvoted your question @user9181286, and I understood the confusion with Goswin, don't worry. Please, re-accept my answer.

Comment: @gsamaras Consider [not requesting accept](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305468/2410359).

Comment: The fact that the OP accepted the answer, and then un-accepted it confuses me. An accepted answer is very useful for future readers, since it signals that this answer solves the problem in question @chux.

Comment: @gsamaras oh i didnt know that how to accept answers. Now i have done. Sorry and thanks

Comment: No problem @user9181286, I was just confused, thank you!